# Facebook "Like" button count the same with two different URL's

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I used Facebook's open graph interface to generate necessary meta tags to annotate my page.

The value I gave for `fb:admins` was my own personal account user ID.

All other values, including the URLs, were different, but for some reason both Like buttons are showing the same count - what could be causing this?

{edit: the domains are culebrais4lovers.com and acueductospr.com)

Comment: When you run the URLs through [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) are they both validating? neither is redirecting to another URL via a HTTP redirect, `og:url` tag or `<link rel="canonical"` tag?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your time helping me out. I've entered both domains in Fb's debugger, the missing og tag is "id" or "admin". Trying to fix it myself, I just removed both tags, from both index pages (the domains are culebrais4lovers.com and acueductospr.com) to see if the counters reset, but they still render the same count for both...

Answer (score 1):

You're pointing the Like buttons on both domains at the same place (acueductospr.com)

On your sample page, `http://culebrais4lovers.com`
you have this HTML:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.acueductospr.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=segoe+ui&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Change the like button on culebrais4lovers.com to point to culebrais4lovers.com

Comment: Much obliged Igy, I had missed that one altogether! I changed it, notwithstanding, after refreshing the page, the counter still yields 143 "Likes" for the site, which coincides with Acueductospr.com's count. I'll give Facebook a couple of hours, maybe it's too early for the change to take effect. Again, thanks!

Comment: Said and done! Just came back from lunch, after hour and a half and there! Culebrais4lovers.com's counter reflect the only two likes it's had so far! Thanks Igy for the help! :)